# How to remove JQuery scrolltop function from a specific page

Tags: jquery

Basically, I have a navbar which changes the logo image from transparent to full colour on scroll.

I don't want this to happen on a certain page, for example, my search results page (/toursearch).

This is the JQuery I am using below.

```
if (windowWidth > 991) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('.logo-desk a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/logo/holts-logo-fill.png');
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 0) {
            $('.logo-desk a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/logo/holts-logo-trans.png');
        }
    });
}
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is `windowWidth` initialized?

Answer (score 0):

you can put a logic like check a div or any other html element with id which is present only on page where scroll logic required and don't run logic if it is not there.

Lets say you have `<div id="pageScroll"></div>` on page where scroll logic required then write script as below

```
if (windowWidth > 991) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if($('#pageScroll').length>0) {
         if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('.logo-desk a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/logo/holts-logo-fill.png');
         }
         if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 0) {
            $('.logo-desk a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/logo/holts-logo-trans.png');
          }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This navigation is global. The only thing I can possibly do to include a specific class on the tour search is to add a class to the body tag (body class="search-results")

Comment: yes, even you can have one global variable like `enableScroll=false` and make it true or false for required page load and use it in scroll function

Answer (score 0):

**script.js**

```
var check = $("[disbled-scrollFun=true]");
if (!check) {
    function scrollFun() {
        if (windowWidth > 991) {
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
                    $('.logo-desk a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/logo/holts-logo-fill.png');
                }
                if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 0) {
                    $('.logo-desk a img').attr('src', '/Includes/images/logo/holts-logo-trans.png');
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**any.html**

add to body or any tag

```
<body disbled-scrollFun="true">

</body>
```